# Disable eslint error with Vuejs and v-html

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, eslint

I use Nuxt 2 with Vue 2 and vuetify.

My vscode was updated and I am getting an eslint error with v-html.

The code is:

```
 <v-list-item-title
   v-html="`${parent.genFilteredText(item.nome)}`"
   >
 </v-list-item-title>
```

and the error is:

```
    [vue/no-v-text-v-html-on-component]

Using v-html on component may break component's content.
```

Before this problem, I used
`<!--eslint-disable vue/no-v-html-->`   on top of my code and I had no problem

but now this is not enough.

I have tried

```
<!--eslint-disable vue/no-v-text-v-html-on-component-->
```

but no look

Comment: did you relint the file after adding the disable comment?  you might also try disabling the rule app-wide in your [eslint config](https://eslint.org/docs/latest/use/configure/configuration-files#using-configuration-files).  Within `"rules": {}` add `"vue/no-v-text-v-html-on-component": 0`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A simple way is,use v-html inside component!

```
 <v-list-item-title v-html="`${parent.genFilteredText(item.nome)}`>

 </v-list-item-title>
```

Change to one of the following modes.

```
<v-list-item-title>
    <span v-html="`${parent.genFilteredText(item.nome)}`"></span>
</v-list-item-title>

// OR
<v-list-item-title>
    <div v-html="`${parent.genFilteredText(item.nome)}`"></div>
</v-list-item-title>

// OR
<v-list-item-title>
    <p v-html="`${parent.genFilteredText(item.nome)}`"></p>
</v-list-item-title>
```